# Gauge implementation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to implement the gauge in iOS:

[image: gauge]

Can anyone provide me some idea about how to do this?

I've referred [MeterView for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/meterview) but have no idea about how to customize it.

Comment: You need to describe what you've tried so far, and what level of programming experience you have, and what level of iPhone programming experience you have.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like they are using 3 views. A background view, the needle view and a foreground semi-transparent gloss view.

The background and gloss views are static regular UIImageViews. The needle is a UIImageView with a  affine rotation transformation applied to it.

Assuming your needle UIImage view is called needle:

```
UIImageView *needle = ...;

float theAngle = ...; //How much to rotate, note that this is in radians not degrees

needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(theAngle); // This rotates your needle UIImageView
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply guys...
Actually, it has a background view (three colors) which is static, but the values plotted around the semi-circle is dynamic and also in floating point.
I tried with that meterView class, but it's not displaying all the values, For Ex : If I give values from 0.1(min) to 1.0(max), it should display like 0.1, 0.2, 0.3..., upto 1.0.
But what happens is, it display values by missing few of them ..like 0.1,   0.3,   0.8,  1.0.Any help??

Comment: Without seeing your source code or much more information, I have no way to help with that.

Comment: This is the Needle Layer function :
 CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, self.width);
CGFloat centerX = layer.frame.size.width / 2.0;
 CGFloat centerY = layer.frame.size.height / 2.0;
CGFloat endX = (1 + self.length) * centerX;
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, centerX, centerY);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, endX, centerY); 
 CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

This draws the Line in the context.Then I  rotate it with this function :
needleLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1);
and it points exactly, but I need to place my own needle image instead of that Line drawn